# How to unit test React Bootstrap Modal with mocha and chai?

Tags: reactjs, mocha.js, chai, react-bootstrap

I want to test nodes of my react bootstrap modal component with chai and mocha.

I have an error when I try to find node like ***Modal.Header*** or ***Modal.Footer***... Error says they are undefined. So, what is the way to test nodes of this component?

This is my **react bootstrap modal component**:

```
import React from 'react'
import {Modal, Button, Glyphicon} from 'react-bootstrap'
const CustomModal = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      showModal: false
    };
  },
  open() {
    this.setState({showModal: true});
  },
  close() {
    this.setState({showModal: false});
  },
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Button className="floatRight"
                  bsStyle={this.props.bsStyle}
                  bsSize="small"
                  onClick={this.open}
          >
            <Glyphicon glyph={this.props.glyphicon}/>
            {this.props.modalTextButton}
          </Button>
          <Modal show={this.state.showModal} onHide={this.close}>
            <Modal.Header closeButton>
              <Modal.Title>{this.props.title}</Modal.Title>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body>
              <h5>{this.props.heading}</h5>
              <hr />
              {this.props.element}
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer>
              <Button onClick={this.close}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        </div>
    )
  }
});
```

This is my **unit test**:

```
import React from 'react';
import { expect } from 'chai';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import sinon from 'sinon';
import {Button, Glyphicon, Modal} from 'react-bootstrap';

import CustomModal from '../../src/components/tibco/generics/custom-modal';

function handleNew() {
  this.refs.modalFormNewReview.close();
}

describe('<CustomModal />', () => {
  it('CustomModal', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <CustomModal ref="modalFormNewReview" bsStyle="success" modalTextButton="New" glyphicon='plus'
                     title='New'
                     heading="Write here..."
                     element={<div></div>}/>
    );

    const divs = wrapper.find('div');
    const buttons = wrapper.find('Button');
    const glyphicons = wrapper.find('Glyphicon').get(0).props;
    const modals = wrapper.find('Modal').get(0).props;
    const modalHeaders = wrapper.find('Modal.Header').get(0).props;
    const modalTitles = wrapper.find('Modal.Title').get(0).props;
    const modalBodies = wrapper.find('Modal.Body').get(0).props;
    const modalFooters = wrapper.find('Modal.Footer').get(0).props;
    const h5 = wrapper.find('h5').get(0).props;
    const hr = wrapper.find('hr').get(0).props;
    expect(wrapper.equals(
        <div {...divs.get(0).props}>
          <Button {...buttons.get(0).props}>
            <Glyphicon {...glyphicons}/>
          </Button>
          <Modal {...modals}>
            <Modal.Header {...modalHeaders}>
              <Modal.Title {...modalTitles}/>
            </Modal.Header>
            <Modal.Body {...modalBodies}>
              <h5 {...h5}/>
              <hr {...hr}/>
            </Modal.Body>
            <Modal.Footer {...modalFooters}>
              <Button {...buttons.get(1).props}>Close</Button>
            </Modal.Footer>
          </Modal>
        </div>
    )).to.equal(true);
  });
});
```

And the **trace log**:

```
  1) <CustomModal /> CustomModal:
     TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined
      at Context.<anonymous> (custom-modal.spec.js:28:26)
      at callFn (D:\Outils dev\_projet_pycharm\tibco_react\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:315:21)
      at Test.Runnable.run (D:\Outils dev\_projet_pycharm\tibco_react\node_modules\mocha\lib\runnable.js:308:7)
      at Runner.runTest (D:\Outils dev\_projet_pycharm\tibco_react\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:422:10)
      at D:\Outils dev\_projet_pycharm\tibco_react\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:533:12
      at next (D:\Outils dev\_projet_pycharm\tibco_react\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:342:14)
      at D:\Outils dev\_projet_pycharm\tibco_react\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:352:7
      at next (D:\Outils dev\_projet_pycharm\tibco_react\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:284:14)
      at Immediate._onImmediate (D:\Outils dev\_projet_pycharm\tibco_react\node_modules\mocha\lib\runner.js:320:5)
```

If I remove all nodes like Modal.*Something* in my test, it return false...